# Is it possible to extract a message from the commit and put it as a topic in the pre-push?

Tags: bash, git, git-bash, githooks, git-push

I have almost 3 days thinking about it and I can't find a way to make me add a topic without having to do a git push.

Is there any way to modify your push after doing a git push?

Let me explain:

I'm trying to make a pre-push extract a specific value from the message and put it as a topic so I can do this:

```
git commit -m "CELL:ANT-1234 Testing pre-push"

git push master
```

Be equal to:

```
git commit -m "CELL:ANT-1234 Testing pre-push"

git push master -o topic=ANT-1234
```

I have managed to prepare everything and have the topic and message prepared without problems but I can't find a way to put it in the push without having to do another git push inside the pre-push, this makes me do the push 2 times and... although it works, in the terminal I get an error because when it is executed 2 times it tells me that there are no changes.

I have managed to get this far:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read local_ref local_sha remote_ref remote_sha
do
  FULL_COMMIT_MESSAGE=$(git log -1 --pretty=%B $local_sha)
  MESSAGE=$(echo "$FULL_COMMIT_MESSAGE" | awk '{print $1}')
  TOPIC=$(echo "$remote_ref" | awk -F 'topic=' '{print $2}')

  # If the value of the topic is not specified in the flag, we obtain it from the CELL identifier
  echo "Validating if topic are set"

  if [ -z "$TOPIC" ]; then
    if echo "$MESSAGE" | grep -iE '^CELL:(ANT|JDRL)' > /dev/null; then
      TOPIC=$(echo "$MESSAGE" | awk -F ':' '{print $2}')
      echo "The topic are set with value -> ${TOPIC}"
      # PROBLEM HERE
      git push --push-option=topic=$TOPIC origin "$local_sha:$remote_ref$TOPIC"
      exit 0
    fi
  fi

  echo "Validating that the commit set message is correct"
  echo $MESSAGE
  if ! echo "$MESSAGE" | grep -iE '^CELL:(ANT|JDRL)' > /dev/null; then
    echo "ERROR: Commit message must start with 'CELL:ANT' or 'CELL:JDRL'"
    exit 1
  fi

  echo "Validate if exist a topic in this commit"
  if [ -z "$TOPIC" ]; then
    echo "ERROR: Flag not found -o topic=XXX or commit message does not start with 'CELL:ANT' or 'CELL:JDRL'"
    exit 1
  fi
done
```

my problem is in:

```
git push --push-option=topic=$TOPIC origin "$local_sha:$remote_ref$TOPIC"
```

isn't there another way to add the topic just to the first push I did in the terminal instead of the pre-push?

Answer (score 1):

Pre-push is a validator, if you want to control the push options you're going to have to script it, probably a git alias is best because it allows easy repo-local overrides.